# Mount Google AppEngine as Windows Drive

Tags: sftp, server-message-block, cloud-hosting, google-app-engine, fuse

The plan is to use Google AppEngine as closed cloud datastore, not for content delivery, for our cloud based Windows Server 2003 machines.

How could Google AppEngine be mounted as a drive with a driveletter or as a linked directory for the Windows Server 2003 filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into this myself. There are a couple of WebDAV servers for App Engine:

- [gae-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/gae-webdav/) (Java); and
- [gaedav](http://code.google.com/p/gaedav/) (Python)

I haven't tried either of these, and there isn't a lot of documentation for either of them, so I don't have a lot of information. But if you can run a WebDAV server on App Engine, it should be easy to mount it from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

They only way I've seen is via [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/igeneration/map-a-network-drive-to-your-online-skydrive-amazon-s3-or-google-apps/2650) ZDnet article.

Comment: What does that have to do with GAE?